# System.Exception: Table has no (public) columns

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin.android

I'm developing for Android on visual studio 2015 using Xamarin.Android and I'm getting the following error on the PCL project:

```
Unhandled Exception:
10-04 01:47:04.594 E/mono    ( 3322): System.Exception: Table has no (public) columns
10-04 01:47:04.594 E/mono    ( 3322):   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, CreateFlags createFlags) [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0 
10-04 01:47:04.594 E/mono    ( 3322):   at SQLite.Net.Async.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<CreateTablesAsync>b__0 () [0x0002b] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My packaging properties are setting `Use Shared Runtime` off.

My linker properties are set to link `Sdk and User Assemblies`.

I'm supporting both `arm` and `x86` architectures and my `Java Mas Heap Size` is `1G`.

I already search about this error, but I couldn't find anythig relevent.

The error occurs when `SQLite` tries to create a table for this entity:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User : IBusinessEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using `SQLite.Net.Async-PCL` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

The nuget package `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` was missing and I was getting this random error. Now it is fixed.

I also change my linker properties to `None`. Not sure it is necessary.